# In Jest, how to test if a non-mocked method in a component is being run on click?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

Previously I have created mock functions and was able to test if they were being called by using something like `expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` for example.

However I have a situation where I want to see how, when I simulate a click on a hamburger menu, do I access a specific method within a component in a way that I can test it in an `expect`?

I know that I can reach it on click, because if I put a console.log into it, it fires.

I have an element in html:

```
<hamburger class="hamburger" @click.native="toggleMobileNav"/>
```

My method is:

```
toggleMobileNav() {
      console.log('this console log works on click');
      //...add classes to nav for css
    },
```

in my test I need to do something like this:

```
it('should be able to toggle nav in mobile', async () => {
        wrapper.find('.hamburger').trigger('click');

        expect(notebookNav.toggleMobileNav()).toHaveBeenCalled(); //doesn't work because it is not a mock or spy function
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to spy your method, then triggering click event should be fine, something like:

```
it('should be able to toggle nav in mobile', () => {
  const toggleMobileNavSpy = jest.spyOn(notebookNav, 'toggleMobileNav');

  expect(toggleMobileNavSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  wrapper.find('.hamburger').trigger('click');
  expect(toggleMobileNavSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  toggleMobileNavSpy.mockClear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to also use jest.spyOn to mock an emit in a child component? @AdriSolid

Comment: Mmm not sure, did you check vue-test-utils? https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/emitted.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is to setup a spy on the `toggleMobileNav` method https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

```
it('should be able to toggle nav in mobile', async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(notebookNav, 'toggleMobileNav');
        wrapper.find('.hamburger').trigger('click');

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
        spy.mockRestore();
    })
```

It works much similar to mocking but without replacing the logic.